# How do I setup Intel SGX on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, hardware, intel, intel-cpu, sgx

I want to use Intel SGX on Ubuntu.

I have a Dell Inspiron with an [Intel i7-8550U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122589/intel-core-i7-8550u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html), and that CPU supports SGX. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 from a bootable flash drive (my main OS is Windows 10, typically I use a VM for my Linux dev, but a VM seems unable to access the SGX chip). I have set SGX to "enabled" mode in my BIOS settings.

I have downloaded the latest version of the SGX SDK from [here](https://download.01.org/intel-sgx/linux-2.5/ubuntu18.04-server/).
I have downloaded the icls client from [here](http://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/11414/iclsClient-1.45.449.12-1.x86_64.rpm). I then install it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo alien --scripts Downloads/iclsClient-1.45.449.12-1.x86_64.rpm
sudo dpkg -i iclsclient_1.45.449.12-2_amd64.deb
sudo ./sgx_linux_x64_driver_778dd1f.bin
sudo dpkg -i libsgx-enclave-common_2.5.100.49891-bionic1_amd64.deb
sudo ./sgx_linux_x64_sdk_2.5.100.49891.bin
source sgxsdk/environment
```

The sdk includes some examples. I am able to run them in debug mode, but they are not working in hardware mode.

Any thoughts on why? Has anyone successfully run (the 2.5 version of) the SGX SDK using Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you follow instructions [here](https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx)?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.tenforums.com/antivirus-firewalls-system-security/101389-sgx-setting-choose-bios.html) is relevant.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483854/intel-sgx-software-guard-extensions-and-linux-mint-19-driver-installation

Comment: [This](https://download.01.org/intel-sgx/linux-2.6/ubuntu18.04-server/) is newer, although it probably doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: Which Inspiron model? Please get the technical model number from the serial number plate, then click [edit] and add that model number to your question. If you can't find the serial number plate, please provide the Service Tag. Please do not click Add Comment; instead, use [edit].